# Call sub from child usercontrol

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8

I've got a usercontrol which should call a Sub of the parent page when it was tapped. But I can't reach it with `this.Parent` (or `Me.Parent`) and so on.

So how can I access properties and subs from the page class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call a sub directly from the usercontrol but raise an event and then respond to this event in the Form. I have assumed you are using Winforms.

In the usercontrol:

```
'declare the event
Public Event ControlClick()

'raise the event when the control is clicked
Private Sub UserControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    RaiseEvent ControlClick()
End Sub
```

In the Form:

```
Private Sub UserControl1_ControlClick1() Handles UserControl1.ControlClick
    MessageBox.Show("Control was clicked")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it's not calling a Sub directly but an event works too.